# Habilitar variante first en tailwind

Tags: css, tailwind

Me gustaría habilitar la variante first de tailwind, pero no consigo hacer que funcione

Este es mi archivo de configuración

```
const production = !process.env.ROLLUP_WATCH;
const colors = require('tailwindcss/colors'); // https://tailwindcss.com/docs/customizing-colors#color-palette-reference
module.exports = {
  // important: true,
  variants: {
    margin: ['responsive', 'hover', 'first'],
  },
  future: {
    purgeLayersByDefault: true,
    removeDeprecatedGapUtilities: true,
  },
  plugins: [
    require('tailwind-scrollbar'),
    require('@tailwindcss/forms'),
  ],
  purge: {
    content: ['./src/**/*.svelte'],
    enabled: production, // disable purge in dev
  },

  theme: {
    extend: {
      fontFamily: {
        lato: ['Lato', 'lato'],
        'essonnes-display': ['essonnes-display'],
      },
      gridAutoColumns: {
        'min-24': 'minmax(6rem, 1fr)',
      },
    },

    colors: {
      transparent: 'transparent',
      current: 'currentColor',
      black: colors.black,
      'black-secondary': 'var(--black-secondary)',
      white: colors.white,
      gray: colors.warmGray,
      'gray-light': 'var(--gris-light)',
      background: 'var(--color-background)',
      red: {
        primary: 'var(--rojo-primary)',
        secondary: 'var(--rojo-secondary)',
      },
      gold: {
        cove: 'var(--gold)',
      },
      brown: {
        primary: 'var(--marron-primary)',
        secondary: 'var(--marron-secondary)',
        tertiary: 'var(--marron-tertiary)',
      },
    },
    // variants: {
    //   extend: {
    //     margin: ['first'],
    //   },
    // },
    // variants: {
    //   extend: {
    //     margin: ['first'],
    //   },
    // },
  },
};
```

y esta es la clase que quiero crear, diciendome que la variente `first` no existe.

```
.title {
    @apply text-lg uppercase border-b-2 border-gold-cove my-8 first:my-0;
 }
```

Esta es la [documentación](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/hover-focus-and-other-states#first-child) que he consultado